# Use of uninitialized value $elements[6] in pattern match (m//)

Tags: perl

I am trying to run a MitoSite software which is written in Perl. I am not very familiar with perl scripting, and I get the following error:

```
needLargeMem: trying to allocate 0 bytes (limit: 100000000000)
Use of uninitialized value $elements[6] in pattern match (m//) at MitoSAlt1.1.pl line 221, <CONFIG> line 75.
```

I guess I have to change something in this piece, but I have no clue since I do not understand it well.

```
sub check_paired{
  my $check_paired = 0;
  my $path = shift;
  my $line = `zcat $path|tail -n 1`;
  my @elements = split(/\t/, $line);

  $check_paired = 1 if $elements[6]=~m/\/.$/;
  return $check_paired;
}
```

Comment: The output of `zcat $path | tail -n 1` is expected to contain at least 7 tab delimited fields. In your case, there are 6 or less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "uninitialized" message is a warning that means that the `@elements` array has fewer than 7 items in it.  You could avoid that warning by checking how many items are in the array before you check the item at index 6:

```
sub check_paired{
  my $check_paired = 0;
  my $path = shift;
  my $line = `zcat $path|tail -n 1`;
  my @elements = split(/\t/, $line);

  if (@elements > 6) {
      $check_paired = 1 if $elements[6]=~m/\/.$/;
  }
  return $check_paired;
}
```